# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: php, mysql

```
$epic=$_REQUEST['epic'];
$sql = "UPDATE std_id SET epic_no='$epic'' WHERE v_fname='$name' AND v_lname='$lname' AND gen='$gen' AND age= '$age' AND as_id='$as_id'";
```

in second line of this code gettig this error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...

Comment: *"for the right syntax to use near..."* - Ok, keep going........ `near '` maybe?

Comment: `epic_no='$epic''` change to `epic_no='$epic'`

Comment: I would be **VERY** careful about how you're doing that, look into using PDO, because you're passing raw user input straight to your database, which is a huge problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please indent your code.

```
$epic = $_REQUEST['epic'];
$sql = "UPDATE std_id SET epic_no='$epic'' WHERE v_fname='$name' AND v_lname='$lname' AND gen='$gen' AND age= '$age' AND as_id='$as_id'";
```

**First** problem: you are not escaping variables ($epic and the others). Use `addslashes()` at least.

**Second** problem: you have two single apis near `$epic`, so correct your query as this:

`UPDATE std_id SET epic_no='$epic' WHERE v_fname='$name' AND v_lname='$lname' AND gen='$gen' AND age= '$age' AND as_id='$as_id'`

**Third** problem: please don't use `$_REQUEST`. It's so generic. Use `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

**Fourth** problem: table and columns names. It's not a really problem, but they are so weird and confusing.

Comment: Not my downvote here but I have a pretty good guess as to who did. You didn't deserve that.

Comment: We are clairvoyant "to a certain extent" aren't we? ;-) *lol*

Comment: Sorry I will not repeat this mistake

Comment: Rather than `addslashes()` a comment telling OP about [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) would be better

Comment: You might have an extra single quote after `epic_no='$epic''` as well

Comment: Riggs, you're right! It was a simple introduction to it.